# Can't insert current date and time into Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> is not working to insert the current date and time into Excel 2013.

How can I fix that?

**UPDATE**

Glitch disappeared when Excel restart, so nobody knows the reason and I awarded just "direct" answer.

**UPDATE 2**

Suppose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> is not working and Excel restart doesn't help.

What can prevent shortcut from working?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Nothing happens

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I insert the current data and time in Excel?

To insert the current date and time, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> (semicolon), then <kbd>Space</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> (colon).

---

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> (semicolon)  Insert current date
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> (colon)     Insert current
>   time

Source [Excel 2013 Shortcuts](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Excel_2013.html)

Comment: I know this, but suppose it is not working.

Comment: Do other control keys work?

Comment: Yes, most other control keys work

Answer (score 3):

> What can prevent shortcut from working?

If you switch your keyboard to a language that has the semicolon on a different key that requires <kbd>Shift</kbd> to type it and then start Excel, the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> doesn't work. The shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> may still work for inserting time.

Switching the keyboard back to English may solve the problem in some cases, but not always. Closing and reopening the document may also not help. The only reliable way I found to solve the problem is restarting Excel after switching the keyboard to English (or a language that doesn't require <kbd>Shift</kbd> to type the semicolon).

Answer (score 0):

If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> is not working, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> almost certainly *will work*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my set-up was only mentioned in one website, called "nutsandboltsspeedtraining.com". I had reinstalled TinySpell the other day, a very useful spellchecker that runs in the background, but unknown to me the latest version uses Ctrl+; as a keyboard shortcut within the app, which disabled it in Excel. Cancelling the shortcut in TinySpell settings restored normal service.

There are probably plenty of other little utilities running in the background that could do this.